# How to translate lookup placeholder text?

Tags: translation, translation-workbench

I cant find the way to translate the colored text, can you help me?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to translate standard object labels.

Go to `'Customize' > 'Tab Names and Labels' > 'Rename Tabs and Labels'` , then select the language you want to translate the custom / standard object label and then click on `Edit` besides the object and change the text according to language. In below screenshot, I translated for object `Test Object`:

[image]

**OUTPUT:**

**BEFORE:**

[image]

**AFTER:**

[image]